# Htaccess-how to rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to hide php,html extension in address bar.i have htdocs folder. in htdocs folder had index.php file and folders.i want to show in address bar like this: 
'index.php?page=exams' is possible
can i add any code in my exsting files?

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

To hide all file extensions, You can use the following line in htaccess :

```
Options +Multiviews
```

This will let you access /index.php as /index,,

Comment: Thank's for your answer!.how to show www.example.com/index?page=exam ,in exam folder have exam.php.